# How to validate if the status code returned is Successful i.e any of the 2xx HTTP status codes using Rest Assured?

Tags: java, testing, rest-assured

I would like to assert if the status code returned is any of the 2xx series i.e 200 or 201 or 204. I don't want to do it the old fashioned way
e.g.

```
if(response.statusCode() == 200 || response.statusCode() == 201 || 
   response.statusCode() == 204) {
     
     \\...
  }
```

Is there any better way to do?

Comment: So how to test if a number is at least 200 but no more that 299?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yes. From 200 to 299. Or sometimes in the 4xx series.

Comment: That was intended as a hint - how might you check whether a number is between x and y without exhaustively checking whether it's equal to x, x+1, ..., y-1, y?

Answer (score 2):

import io.restassured.internal.http.Status;

```
Assert.assertTrue(Status.SUCCESS.matches(response.statusCode())); // true for family of 
2xx eg 200 or 201
```

Reference: [Mapping of HTTP response codes to a constant 'success' or 'failure' value.](https://javadoc.io/static/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.3.0/io/restassured/internal/http/Status.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **CustomTypeSafeMatcher**

```
 given()
.
.
.
.statusCode(new CustomTypeSafeMatcher<>("2xx StatusCode") {
   @Override
   protected boolean matchesSafely(Integer item) {
         return Status.SUCCESS.matches(item);
   }
})
```